# deal with a div within a while loop 

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, loops, html

I have a while loop shows data items from a database, I want to deal with each item apart, but what I get is just the first div, for each iteration, I wanna take the 'id' of current iteration and deal with it, it's look like 'like' in facebook, when I click on the first 'like' a jquery runs a `$.post(..)` function and all go fine: treatements done with this id,
but when I click on other next 'like's the post methode still sends the first id (checked out by firebug),
code:

```
<script type='text/javascript>
  $("#like").click(function(){
    $.post("done.php",
      {id:$("#id").val()},
      function(data){
        ...
      });
   });
</script>

<body>
$result = myqsl_query("select * from ...");
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result){
..
echo "<input id='id' value='$fetch[0]'>
<a href='...' id='like'>like</a>";
..
</body>
```

I hope I succeeded to describe the problem!
Any solution with any language will be appreciated!
Regards.

Comment: Maybe it is just me - but if you have set id="like" on every like anchor you can't succeed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's have to be unique in a HTML file. If you have multiple elements with the same ID, the browsers only return the first one. Thus, `$('#like').click()` only attaches the click event handler to the first element with this ID.

You have to use classes instead:

```
<script type='text/javascript>
  $(".like").click(function(){
    $.post("done.php",
      {id:$(this).prev().val()},
      function(data){
        ...
      });
   });
</script>

<body>
<?php
    $result = myqsl_query("select * from ...");
?>
<?php while(($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result))): ?>
    <input class="something" value="<?php echo $fetch[0]; ?>" />
    <a href="..." class="like">like</a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</body>
```

Further notes:

- You should not `echo` HTML, it makes it hard to maintain. Instead, embed PHP in HTML, like I showed above.
- I also use the [*alternative syntax for control structures*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), which is easier to read if you mix HTML and PHP.

Comment: Yes, I forgot, I tried it with classes, and I modified the jquery function:$(".like).click(...), but did not solv the problem, always I get the same data posted to done.php, I wonder if there is a way to initialise the data to be sent  ????

Comment: Thanks Felix for your advices, experience appears over here!

Answer (score 2):

If your final output looks something like this:

```
<input id='id' value='someValue'>
<a href='someLink' id='like'>like</a>
...
<input id='id' value='someValue'>
<a href='someLink' id='like'>like</a>
```

Will cause you a problem as an id needs to be unique per dom.

You could rework it to use classes:

```
<input class="likeId" value='someValue'>
<a href='someLink' class='like'>like</a>
...
<input class="likeId" value='someValue'>
<a href='someLink' class='like'>like</a>
```

And than in your click handler.

```
$(".like").click(function(){
    $.post("done.php",
      {id:$(this).prev('.likeId').val()},
      function(data){
        ...
    });
});
```

Depending if the input value is hidden you could remove it completely and use html `data-*` attributes and `.data()` assuming if you can use jQuery greater than 1.4.3.

```
<a href='someLink' class='like' data-likeId='someValue'>like</a>
<a href='someLink' class='like' data-likeId='someValue'>like</a>

$(".like").click(function(){
    $.post("done.php",
      {id:$(this).data('likeId')},
      function(data){
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked very very nicely as wanted, thanks MArk, u look like kinda an expert ^^!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript>
   $(".like").click(function(){
      $.post("done.php",
         {id:$("#id").prev("input").val())},
         function(data){
         ...
      });
   });
</script>

<body>
    $result = myqsl_query("select * from ...");
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result){
    ..
    echo "<input name='id' value='$fetch[0]'>
    <a href='...' class='like'>like</a>";
    ..
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You say "first like" so I am assuming that you have many 'like' buttons in the page.

```
$("#like").click(function(){
```

but standards would tell you that id's are to be unique. Maybe a global variable that iterates and appends the iteration to the id such as `'#like1', '#like2'` etc.

Not sure if this will lead you to your answer but it is something that needs consideration.